# Tail multiple files and output as additional column with 'find' results

Tags: bash, find, tail

Would like to pull the last line of text from a specific (multiple) files in a directory. Additionally, I'd like the results to be in a more traditional column format (like `ls`) with path, rather than the typical format of `tail`.

From the following results {1}, I'd like to append as an additional column the last row of data {2}

Where {1} =  `find . -iname 'updated.txt'`, and 
      {2} =  `tail -n1`

I'm using `bash` in Mavericks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
find . -iname 'updated.txt' -exec ls -l {} \; -exec tail -n1 {} \;
```

A simpler alternative but with less control over the formatting of `ls`:

```
find . -iname 'updated.txt' -ls -exec tail -n1 {} \;
```

**UPDATE**

As you said in comments, you prefer to have the `ls` output and the `tail` output side by side for each file.

You could run a subshell for each match to `echo` the output of the two commands side by side:

```
find . -iname 'updated.txt' -exec sh -c 'echo $(ls -l "{}") $(tail -n1 "{}")' \;
```

Similarly, you could use `paste`:

```
find . -iname 'updated.txt' -exec bash -c 'paste <(ls -l "{}") <(tail -n1 "{}")' \;
```

Or you could run the two `find` commands in parallel and paste their output side by side like this:

```
paste \
  <(find . -iname 'updated.txt' -exec ls -l {} \;) \
  <(find . -iname 'updated.txt' -exec tail -n1 {} \;)
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep all the results on the same line however?  Currently each time tail runs, it places each result on a new line.

Comment: You want first a listing of `ls -l`, one line per file, plus at the end one more line with the content of the last lines pasted together like columns, like that?

Comment: All inline: I'd like `tail` to be appended to `ls -l` as an additional column rather than have `tail` add a newline.

Comment: The first two options have issues encountering spaces in the result set.  <br/>  <br/>  The last option worked though.  Could you explain how it functions?  <br/> `paste \
  <br/>  <(find . -iname 'updated.txt' -exec ls -l {} \;) \
  <br/>  <(find . -iname 'updated.txt' -exec tail -n1 {} \;)`

Comment: True, I fixed the issues with spaces. The `<(...)` in `paste <(cmd1) <(cmd2)` is called *Process Substitution*. The idea is replacing `<(...)` with a named pipe, which contains the output of the commands inside. You can read about it in `man bash` under the **Process Substitution** section.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find . -iname 'updated.txt' -printf '%M %u %g %s %Tc %p\t' -exec tail -n1 {} \;
```

Output will be like:

```
-rw-r--r-- user group 4853 2013-12-22T00:58:32 MSK ./path/updated.txt    Last line of the updated.txt.
```

Comment: And why downvoted, may I ask?

Comment: One thing to note is that this won't work out of the bag on Mac: printf isn't supported in find. After installing findutils it works like a champ. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kris You’re welcome. :) As for me, now I know that ‘Mavericks’ is OS X release (yes, it was worth mentioning).